# Projective $R$-module with $R=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\mid a\equiv b\pmod 5\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

In my assignment, I was asked to show for  $R=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\mid a\equiv b\pmod 5\}$, the $R$-module $M=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\mid 2a\equiv b\pmod 5\}$ with the action by $R$ defined by componentwise multiplication.

(1) Is there a name for such ring and module?

(2)How can we show that it is **projective but not free**?

Among the four definitions for being projective module, the most probable criterion that I can think of is to show that $M$ taking direct sum with some $R$-module will be a $R$-module, but what can that particular module be?

Thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: (1) I think R is equivalent to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+5x)$.

Comment: $M$ is generated as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module by $(1, 2)$ and $(0, 5)$, so it's certainly also generated as an $R$-module by $(1, 2)$ and $(0, 5)$.  So, if $M$ is projective, it would necessarily have to be some direct summand of $R^2$ - since by another definition, there would have to be a map $M \to R^2$ such that composing with the map $R^2 \to M, ((a, b), (c, d)) \mapsto (a, b) (1, 2) + (c, d) (0, 5) = (a, 2b + 5d)$ gives the identity.